# How to represent a month of checkboxes in an MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't manage to get my head around how to use MVC to create the following table, and successfully bind it to a model:

[image]

I basically need to keep track of which days of the month an event needs to happen. Here is my attempt at a model:

**EDIT**: This isn't for a month, but for a arbitrary 4 week cycle

```
public class ScheduleViewModel
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }          
    public List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set;}          
}

public class Schedule {
    public int Week { get;set;}
    public Day Day { get;set;}
    public bool IsSelected { get;set;}    
}

public enum Day
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

And I can render a view successfully (that isn't bound to the model). I realise that I would need to use @html.CheckBoxFor in place on my inputs.

Here is a rough copy of my html for the view:

```
@model WebApplication10.Models.ScheduleViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @{
foreach (Day t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day)))
{
    <th>@t</th>
}
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @{
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>Week @i</td>
        @foreach (Day t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Day)))
        {
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        }
    </tr>
}
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

How would I successfully post which check-boxes have been selected? Does my ViewModel make sense?

Comment: I'd say you're roughly on the right track, but you have to take into consideration that a month usually has 5 weeks (only February has 4)

and also you should build your view around your view model not around the enum
in that way you could bind the Value property of your checkbox to the IsSelected property of your view model

Comment: Your not binding to any of your model properties so nothing will be posted back when you submit.

Comment: Ok cool, so I need to create the structure for the Schedules (a prepopulated list of schedules with IsSelected set to false) and then pass the model to the create view and then use bind using @html.checkboxfor

Comment: You might find it easier to break your view models into a `WeekVM` and `DayVM` so its easier to generate the view and strongly ind to your model. I post an answer shortly.

Comment: @memoryofadream thanks - for this application it works in 4 week cycles and doesn't have a specific connection to how many weeks are in a month

Comment: I'd have the constructor for your `Schedule` object take in a DateTime object. Use the month in there to build out an array of Week objects, only filling in the Days that exist in the given month. Also, there is already a [`DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) enum built into the .NET Framework.

Comment: @krillgar thanks - I considered using DayOfWeek but Sunday is set as the first day in the System enum and I want Monday as the first

Comment: You should probably add to your question about how it is just a "random" 4-week period, and not tied into the month. I was about to make an answer for you as well, and it would have been way wrong since I made an incorrect assumption based on missing information.

Comment: @krillgar - apologies > updated the question

Comment: I reject the premise: that 30 days worth of checkboxes is a good thing.  Instead, there are alternate ways to display this.  What are you trying to accomplish? What's the business goal for this UI? Is it a reminder to take pills? occurring calendar events? Days of the week to send out bills?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Days of a week to take pills. There will be other controls that will auto-populate the checkboxes

Comment: @woggles Then you really only need to display one week at a time, not four.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker They'll need more control than that because prescriptions can run out in the middle of the 4 week period

Comment: @woggles We don't really have enough information; if a prescription runs out (theoretically you know that because you're asking them to enter that information), then perhaps the software should calculate when it's going to run out and give them a notification/refill reminder/let them schedule their new regimen then?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks for the suggestions - that may be developed further down the line, but for now they just want to see the overview of the period

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you change you view model(s) to

```
public class DayVM
{
  public Day Day { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
public class WeekVM
{
  public WeekVM()
  {
    Days = new List<DayVM>();
    Days.Add(new DayVM() { Day = Day.Sunday });
    Days.Add(new DayVM() { Day = Day.Monday });
    .. etc
  }
  public List<DayVM> Days { get; set; }
}
public class ScheduleViewModel
{
  public ScheduleViewModel()
  {
    Weeks = new List<WeekVM>();
    Weeks.Add(new WeekVM());
    .... etc
  }
  public int PatientId { get; set; }          
  public List<WeekVM> Weeks { get; set;}          
}
```

Then in the view

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Weeks.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>Week @i</td>
    for(int j = 0; j < Model.Weeks[i].Days.Count; j++)
    {
      <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Weeks[i].Days[j].IsSelected)
      </td>
    }
  </tr>
}
```

Side note: I don't think you really need you own enum here - your could just use the `DayOfWeek` enumeration, for example `Days.Add(new DayVM() { Day = DayOfWeek.Sunday });`. Note also I have not included an input for the `Day` property since you could easily determine that from its index in the collection. In fact the `Day` property may not be required at all if you manually render the table header row.

Comment: Clean and great solution! @stephen

Comment: Thanks - this works great - I added a hidden input for the day property even though its not really needed and would work well using the array index as you mentioned