# pass table values from view to controller mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

I am working on a project in dot Net + share-point,
In there controller get sharepoint list record & create a list of list object.
In view catch the object as one model and dilplay in a table.

Table view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4sxm.png)

Index.cshtml

```
@using( Html.BeginForm() )
{
<table id = "timeTrackingView" border="1" >

    <tr>
        <th>Projects</th>
        @for (var date = @Model.Dates.AddDays(-(@Model.DateRange-1)); date <= @Model.Dates; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            <th >@date.Day/@date.Month/@date.Year</th>
        }

    </tr>
   @{ double[] totalForToday = new double[@Model.DateRange];}

      @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.TimeTrakings.Count; i++)
      {         
          //var projectName = @Model.TimeTrakings[i][0].ProjectName;       
        int index = 0;     
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model.TimeTrakings[i][0].ProjectName
            </td>
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.TimeTrakings[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                totalForToday[index] = totalForToday[index] + @Model.TimeTrakings[i][j].Hours;
                 var time = @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.TimeTrakings[i][j]);
                <td>@time</td>
              @*@Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.TimeTrakings[i][j].Hours)*@ 

                index++;  
            }

        </tr>
    }

    <tr>
    <td>Total for day</td>
        @foreach(var tot in totalForToday)
        {
            <td>@tot</td>
        }

    </tr>    
</table>
<input type="submit" name="SubmitBtn"/>
}
```

I am trying to get table data into controller.. help me im my code only gettinh hours, need get project name date & hours together.

My controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(TimeTracking timeTracking)
        {
            ////do the logic here 
            return View(this.ReceiveTimeTrackingData());
        }
```

I Used two mode-:
Model1

```
 public class TimeTrackingDetails

        {
             public string ProjectName { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public double Hours { get; set; }        
        }
```

Model 2-:

```
public class TimeTracking

    {
              public List<List<TimeTrackingDetails>> TimeTrakings { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Show you model (you use of `EditorFor(model => @Model.TimeTrakings[i][j])` does not really make sense) and you really need to be using nested collections for this

Comment: You `List<List<T>>` property is messy and you should consider using a view model with nested collections that better represents what you want to display and does not duplicate data (the `ProjectName` and `Date` values). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626914/how-to-represent-a-month-of-checkboxes-in-an-mvc-model/29627829#29627829) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need project name you should create an `input`. Now in your code you have just plain text with this line:

```
@Model.TimeTrakings[i][0].ProjectName
```

Just add another line onder it:

```
@Model.TimeTrakings[i][0].ProjectName
// this line will create additional hidden input and on form post it will be sended to server.
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TimeTrakings[i][0].ProjectName)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me. I added 
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TimeTrakings[i][0].ProjectName) with each attributes. It will return all the records when submitting form.