# Design timetable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Can somebody help me in designing the timetable of the student? The below screenshot data is fetched from the database in 2 Models, the first model have the distinct start_time and the end_time for that student, and the second model have the start_time, end_time and the course details, on the view I'm running a loop over each item in model1 and another internal loops for each day in model2, see the below code for details

The question is: I want to organize the schedule view same as outlook calendar (image 2) generate a square from the start time to the end time, I've tried most of the plugins to manage this without any success.

Thanks

[image: Image2]
[image: Image1]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-body">

            <table class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:white !important;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary align-center">
                        <td class="text-bold" width="10%">Time</td>
                        <td class="text-bold" width="15%">Sunday</td>
                        <td class="text-bold" width="15%">Monday</td>
                        <td class="text-bold" width="15%">Tuesday</td>
                        <td class="text-bold" width="15%">Wednesday</td>
                        <td class="text-bold" width="15%">Thursday</td>
                        <td class="text-bold" width="15%">Saturday</td>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.TimeSlot)
                    {
                        <tr class="align-center">
                            <td class="bg-info text-bold" style="white-space: nowrap;">@item.BEGIN_TIME_DISP - @item.END_TIME_DISP</td>
                            <td class="drop" id="@("Sun" + item.BEGIN_TIME+item.END_TIME)">
                                @foreach (var Sitem in Model.Schedule.Where(i => i.SUN == "U" && i.BEGIN_TIME == @item.BEGIN_TIME && i.END_TIME == @item.END_TIME))
                                {

                                    <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(GetCRNClassRoster('@Sitem.TERM_CODE','@Sitem.COURSE_CRN'));" class="link" title="Click to view class roster">

                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CRN<br />
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CODE
                                        </a><br />
                                        @Sitem.COURSE_TITLE<br />
                                    </span>
                                    @Sitem.ROOM_CODE
                                    <span style="color:darkred; font-size:10px" class="sDate">
                                        <br />
                                        from @Sitem.START_DATE_CHAR to @Sitem.END_DATE_CHAR<br />
                                    </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="drop" id="@("Mon" + item.BEGIN_TIME+item.END_TIME)">
                                @foreach (var Sitem in Model.Schedule.Where(i => i.MON == "M" && i.BEGIN_TIME == @item.BEGIN_TIME && i.END_TIME == @item.END_TIME))
                                {
                                    <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(GetCRNClassRoster('@Sitem.TERM_CODE','@Sitem.COURSE_CRN'));" class="link" title="Click to view class roster">
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CRN<br />
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CODE
                                        </a><br />
                                        @Sitem.COURSE_TITLE<br />
                                    </span>
                                    @Sitem.ROOM_CODE<br />
                                                    <span style="color:darkred; font-size:10px" class="sDate">

                                                        from @Sitem.START_DATE_CHAR to @Sitem.END_DATE_CHAR<br />
                                                    </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="drop" id="@("Tue" + item.BEGIN_TIME+item.END_TIME)">
                                @foreach (var Sitem in Model.Schedule.Where(i => i.TUE == "T" && i.BEGIN_TIME == @item.BEGIN_TIME && i.END_TIME == @item.END_TIME))
                                {
                                    <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(GetCRNClassRoster('@Sitem.TERM_CODE','@Sitem.COURSE_CRN'));" class="link" title="Click to view class roster">
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CRN<br />
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CODE
                                        </a><br />
                                        @Sitem.COURSE_TITLE<br />
                                    </span>
                                    @Sitem.ROOM_CODE<br />
                                                    <span style="color:darkred; font-size:10px" class="sDate">

                                                        from @Sitem.START_DATE_CHAR to @Sitem.END_DATE_CHAR<br />
                                                    </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="drop" id="@("Wed" + item.BEGIN_TIME+item.END_TIME)">
                                @foreach (var Sitem in Model.Schedule.Where(i => i.WED == "W" && i.BEGIN_TIME == @item.BEGIN_TIME && i.END_TIME == @item.END_TIME))
                                {
                                    <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(GetCRNClassRoster('@Sitem.TERM_CODE','@Sitem.COURSE_CRN'));" class="link" title="Click to view class roster">
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CRN<br />
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CODE
                                        </a><br />
                                        @Sitem.COURSE_TITLE<br />
                                    </span>
                                    @Sitem.ROOM_CODE<br />
                                                    <span style="color:darkred; font-size:10px" class="sDate">

                                                        from @Sitem.START_DATE_CHAR to @Sitem.END_DATE_CHAR<br />
                                                    </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="drop" id="@("Thu" + item.BEGIN_TIME+item.END_TIME)">
                                @foreach (var Sitem in Model.Schedule.Where(i => i.THU == "R" && i.BEGIN_TIME == @item.BEGIN_TIME && i.END_TIME == @item.END_TIME))
                                {
                                    <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(GetCRNClassRoster('@Sitem.TERM_CODE','@Sitem.COURSE_CRN'));" class="link" title="Click to view class roster">
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CRN<br />
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CODE
                                        </a><br />
                                        @Sitem.COURSE_TITLE<br />
                                    </span>
                                    @Sitem.ROOM_CODE                                        <br />
                                                    <span style="color:darkred; font-size:10px" class="sDate">

                                                        from @Sitem.START_DATE_CHAR to @Sitem.END_DATE_CHAR<br />
                                                    </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="drop" id="@("Sat" + item.BEGIN_TIME+item.END_TIME)">
                                @foreach (var Sitem in Model.Schedule.Where(i => i.SAT == "S" && i.BEGIN_TIME == @item.BEGIN_TIME && i.END_TIME == @item.END_TIME))
                                {
                                    <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(GetCRNClassRoster('@Sitem.TERM_CODE','@Sitem.COURSE_CRN'));" class="link" title="Click to view class roster">
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CRN<br />
                                            @Sitem.COURSE_CODE
                                        </a><br />
                                        @Sitem.COURSE_TITLE<br />
                                    </span>
                                    @Sitem.ROOM_CODE                                        <br />
                                                    <span style="color:darkred; font-size:10px" class="sDate">

                                                        from @Sitem.START_DATE_CHAR to @Sitem.END_DATE_CHAR<br />
                                                    </span>
                                }
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first thing you need is a view model to represent what you want to display. If will contain a collection property (say  `List<TimeSlotVM>` for each (say) 30 min period which represents table rows. `TimeSlotVM` will contain a collection property (say `List<DayVM>`) to represent the days, and `DayVM` will contain properties for the Course etc, and an `int` property representing the duration in 30 min periods. Then is simply a nested foreach loop and the duration property is used to set the `rowspan` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke create idea, I will give try, the only concern is it might slow the response of the database query.

Comment: Its no different for all the queries you running in the view (which is bad practice). Not a dupe, but look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626914/how-to-represent-a-month-of-checkboxes-in-an-mvc-model/29627829#29627829) for an example of how you model and view should look (in that case `DayVM` has properties for displaying the details of your course and a property for the number of periods that can be use in the nested loop for setting the `rowspan` of the `<td>` element (and you code will be significantly less)

Comment: Is [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZPorRU) the sort of thing you looking for?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes it's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much, please submit as answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current `<table>` layout, you can use the `rowspan` attribute of the `<td>` elements to allow your `Course` to extend down multiple rows vertically.

Your current view code using multiple queries on your data model is difficult to read and test and is duplicating code. You should start by creating view models to represent your display, which in you case means one representing a table cell (containing the properties of `Course` you want to display), one representing a table row (collection of cells), and one representing the table (collection of rows).

```
public class CourseVM // represents a table cell
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    ... // other properties of Course that will be displayed in the view
    public int? TimeSlots { get; set; }
}
```

The `TimeSlot` property (for want of a better name) is used to determine the number of rows (hours) that the `Course` extends down.

```
public class WeekVM // represents a table row
{
    public WeekVM()
    {
        Days = new List<CourseVM>();
        // Hard code for 1 week, but could add a parameter in the constructor to generate a variable number of days
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Days.Add(new CourseVM());
        }
    }
    public List<CourseVM> Days { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleVM // represents the table
{
    public ScheduleVM(DateTime startDate, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
    {
        StartDate = startDate.Date.Add(startTime);
        TimeSlots = new List<WeekVM>();
        // Assume 1 hour slots
        int intervals = (int)((endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes) / 60;
        for (int i = 0; i < intervals; i++)
        {
            TimeSlots.Add(new WeekVM());
        }
    }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public List<WeekVM> TimeSlots { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller, initialize a new instance of `ScheduleVM` and set its properties based on you collection of `Course`

```
// Set parameters (these may come from parameters in the method
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 22);
TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0);
// Get collection of data model
IEnumerable<Course> courses = db.Courses.Where(...);
// Initialize view model
ScheduleVM model = new ScheduleVM(startDate, startTime, endTime);
foreach(Course course in courses)
{
    // Get row and column indexes of the table where this instance needs to be displayed
    int dayIndex = (int)course.StartTime.DayOfWeek;
    int slotIndex = course.StartTime.Hour - startTime.Hours;
    // Determine how any rows this needs to span over
    int timeSlots = (course.EndTime - course.StartTime).Hours;
    // Set view model properties
    var courseVM = model.TimeSlots[slotIndex].Days[dayIndex];
    courseVM.Code = course.Code;
    courseVM.Title = course.Title;
    courseVM.TimeSlots = timeSlots;
    for (int i = 1; i < timeSlots; i++)
    {
        slotIndex++;
        model.TimeSlots[slotIndex].Days[dayIndex].TimeSlots = 0;
    }
}
return View(model);
```

Note that for `rowspan` to work, subsequent rows need to omit the corresponding `<td>` element if a cell above extends into it. In the code above, the `if` block sets the `TimeSlots` value to `0` in subsequent rows so it can be conditionally checked in the view. Then the view is

```
@model ScheduleVM
....
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                <th>@Model.StartDate.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var timeSlot in Model.TimeSlots)
        {           
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.StartDate.AddHours(rowIndex).ToString("hh:mm tt")</td>
                @foreach(var course in timeSlot.Days)
                {
                    if (!course.TimeSlots.HasValue)
                    {       
                        <td></td>
                    }
                    else if (course.TimeSlots > 0)
                    {
                        <td rowspan="@course.TimeSlots">
                            <div class="course">
                                <div>@course.Code</div>
                                .... // other properties of course
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    }   
                }
            </tr>
            rowIndex++;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you just need a bit of css to style it.

Comment: one more request I'm stuck in changing the Timeslot to 30 minutes slot, would you please update the fiddle if possible.

Comment: @AbuYazan I have updated the code to allow any interval (hard coded to 30 minutes in the fiddle) But note that if you specify (say) 60 minute intervals, it expects that the start and end times are also in 60 minute intervals (so if you had a start time of 9.30 and specify 60 minute intervals, it will draw it starting at 9.00.) Also note that this will fail if you have any overlapping times (but that would not make sense anyway and I assume you have checks in place to ensure that there are none)

Answer (score 0):

Full calendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) day view is what you are looking for here.

The library is very extendable, and one that I use constantly.

Comment: I've tried using full calendar, it needs a lot of customization as the schedule is not an actual calendar but a fixed weekly table. will see if any other suggestion using loops and css