# C# help me to use Group By int table Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i Need Table Like This Group By employeeName and Date

Like This

[image]

I Used This Cod but it doesn't work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @{ 
                EmpTimeEntities db = new EmpTimeEntities();
                var EmplyeeTime=
                from c in db.Time_Table
                group c by new
                {
                    c.Emp_Table.EmpName,
                    c.dateEmp,

                } into gcs
                select new TimeEmpModel()
                {
                    empname = gcs.Key.EmpName.,
                    date = gcs.Key.dateEmp.HasValue ? gcs.Key.dateEmp.Value : default(DateTime),
                    time = gcs.ToList(),

            };
        }


          <table>

         </table>


    </div>
</div>
```

any One Can Help Me ??

Comment: That code belongs in your controller, not the view. What is not working?

Comment: where are you binding the data to the html table ?

Comment: he has brought things from DA to the view...what is db context doing here

Comment: Can you  Make example

Comment: Your view model has no relationship to the image. Its need a collection property to represent table rows, which will contain a collection property to represent table columns

Comment: yes  binding the data to the html table

Comment: Stephen Muecke  Please can you help me to work example

Comment: @BlackSword,Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626914/how-to-represent-a-month-of-checkboxes-in-an-mvc-model/29627829#29627829) for some guidance, in particular how your view models need to be.

Answer (score 0):

All the data manipulation should be done in your controller, once the data prepared then it should be represented in view with suitable table, tr, td structure. An Example

```
@model IEnumerable<List_Data_Binding_in_MVC.Models.ModelName>  

@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";  
}  
<div><b>Table Format Data Displaying in ForEach</b><br /></div>  
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">  
    <tr>  
        <th>Prop 1 </th>  
        <th>Prop 2</th>  
    </tr>  
    @foreach (var d in Model)  
    {  
        <tr>  
            <td>@d.Prop1</td>  
            <td>@d.Prop2</td>    
        </tr>  
    }  
</table>
```