# i am not getting right output in View using table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

i want to generate a time table at ruin time (correct out put is correctOutput.jpg )  while i am getting wrong output its image is attached (wrongOutput.jpg). my View code are as follow.

```
<div class="row">
@*Monday Time table*@
@if (ViewBag.MondaySlot != null)
{
var count = 0;

<table class="table-responsive" style="border-style:dashed " border="1">
    <tr>
        @{int TimeSLotCount = ViewBag.MondaySlot.Count;
            TimeSLotCount--;
            }
        <th>Room</th>
        @for (int i = 0; i < TimeSLotCount; i++)
        {
            <th width="100px" style="justify-content:center">@ViewBag.MondaySlot[i].ToShortTimeString()</th>
            count++;
        }

    </tr>
    @{ int ClassRoomCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Course.Count; i++){
            if (i % count == 0)
            {
                @:<tr> 
                    @:<td> 

                    @ViewBag.ClassRoom[ClassRoomCount].BlockNmae
                    <br />
                    @ViewBag.ClassRoom[ClassRoomCount].RoomNumber

                    @:</td>

                ClassRoomCount++;
            }

            else{
                @:<td>
                      @:<span> @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Course[i].C_Name) <br /> @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Course[i].P_ID)</span>
                @:</td>
            }
            if (i % count == 0 || i == ViewBag.Course.Count){
                @:</tr>

        }

     }
     }
```

Wrong output that getting
 [image: CorrectOutput]

Correct output want to get
[image: incorrect output]

Comment: In your first iteration, `i is 0` and `count is 0` so you start a row and add one `<td>` element (the first `if` block,), then it jumps to the 2nd `if` block and since `i` is `0` you end the row. And you do not need your `ClassRoomCount ` variable since that's the same as `i`. Get rid of that awful use of `ViewBag` and create a view model representing your table, which will include a collection of view models representing a row, which in turn will contain a collection property representing the columns, and then its just a very simple nested `foreach` loop in the view

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626914/how-to-represent-a-month-of-checkboxes-in-an-mvc-model/29627829#29627829) for an example of how your view models would be.