# How can i implement a DropDownListFor for List<Dictionary<string, List<Rights>>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, dropdownlistfor

I have two dictionaries `Dictionary<string, List<Rights>>` and a List of these dictionaries `List<Dictionary<string, List<Rights>>>`.

Now I want to have a DropDownListFor for the names of these dictionaries.

For example I have a dictionary to store `PersonModel (name)`  and a list of their `Rights`, and a dictionary store `Groups (name)` and a list of their `Rights`.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Rights>> PersonsWithRights { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Groups")]
public Dictionary<string, List<Rights>> GroupsWithRights { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "--")]
public List<Dictionary<string, List<Rights>>> ObjectsWithRights { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.ObjectsWithRights.FirstOrDefault(), new SelectList(@Model.ObjectsWithRights))
```

The goal would be to have a dropdown with "Persons" and "Groups", and out of this dropdown an "access right matrix", where you can modify the rights.

Here a little "mockup" for Persons:
[image]

Here a little "mockup" for Groups:
[image]

Comment: You want just a single dropdown for persons and groups right?

Comment: @ahmet yes, but out of the selected one I want to create the matrix

Comment: I don't understand the need of matrix. One dropdown; I select a person or a group. Then it shows me a list of rights. Where will be the matrix?

Comment: @ahmet I added a picture to my post for explanation

Comment: Then what is the need of dropdown? Names and groups are listed vertically and rights are listed horizontally. There is no need a dropdown. If you tell me "There are lots of persons and groups" then I ask "What is the need of listing more than one person or group? There is then no need to a list vertically."

Comment: What is the purpose of the dropdown? Are you wanting to change the list of names (or groups) in the LHS column based on the selected option? (and as a side note, using Dictionaries for your data is the worst possible choice, and you will never get proper 2-way model binding - use a view model that represents you view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah I think you understood me right, but how can I achieve this? What is the better way? Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Refer [How to represent a month of checkboxes in an MVC model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626914/how-to-represent-a-month-of-checkboxes-in-an-mvc-model/29627829#29627829) for an example of how your view models and view code would look for correct 2-way model binding

Comment: @StephenMuecke but what is the better way to store `PersonModels` and their rights? (rights are different for each table)

Comment: Although its still not clear what the purpose of the dropdownlist is for (I assume you want to change the values in the LHS column to be either a list of names or a list of groups? - in which case why not just display tables in the view, otherwise have 2 separate views for editing name permissions and group permissions)

Comment: @StephenMuecke your suggestions are right, I added one more picture to my question. What do you mean with display tables in the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176607/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-david-walser).